# How can I refer to a column by its header

Tags: excel, vba

I use this in a module in Excel:

```
Range("FA2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(RC[-85]-RC[-84]) / MAX(RC[-85],RC[-84])"
```

I want to refer to the columns, not by using formulaR1C1 but by the header of each Column

ex.

```
Set rng1 = Range( _
    Range("A1:EU1").Find("HEADER").Offset(1), _
    Range("A1:EU1").Find("HEADER").Offset(1).End(xlDown))
```

How can I make this work?

Thank you

Comment: What's not working with your Find-based approach? It looks like you're definitely on the right track to solving this yourself.

Comment: I am looking for the way to index the "rng1 " into "=ABS(...-...) / MAX(...,...)"

Comment: I'm still not quite sure _exactly_ what you want here. Do you want your formula to contain the column header name or are you unsure how to use rng1 to construct your formula? If it's the latter take a look at [the Address property of the Range object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Make the header a Named Range, then refer to the name.

If the header of column B is "EMPLOYEE", select B1, go to the top left corner where it says B1 and Type Employee, press enter.

You can now refer to B1 as Range("Employee").

Answer (score -2):

you can refer to Excel column simply by using : `Range("A")`

Comment: I wont be able to know the exact column everytime I would like to run this. That's why I would like to refer to it by its header